# How to apply regex to check route param is in array

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I have route like this. I am trying to check if route param `social` is either `facebook`, `google` or `twitter`.

```
Route::get('/login/{social}', 'Auth\LoginController@loginSocial')
->where('social',["facebbok","google","twitter"]);
```

Above route is not working. It asks for regex. Please help.

How to check this ?

Comment: Answer is here. Previously i solved my problem with it.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/4582992

Comment: Previously i solved my problem with this link. Hope you too http://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/4582992

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Route::get('/login/{social}', 'Auth\LoginController@loginSocial')
->where('social','(facebook|google|twitter)');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `where` method on a route instance accepts the name of the parameter and a regular expression, your second parameter isn't a regular expression:

```
Route::get('/login/{social}', 'Auth\LoginController@loginSocial')
->where('social','(facebook|google|twitter)');
```

Here is a valid RegExp

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated what the method signature of the `->where` but at a guess:

```
Route::get('/login/{social}', 'Auth\LoginController@loginSocial')
->where('social', "/^(facebook|google|twitter)$/i");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this condition will helpful for you.

```
Route::get('/login/{social}','Auth\LoginController@loginSocial')
    ->where('social', 'facebook|google|twitter');
```