# How to apply where condition to check route param is in LARGE array

Tags: laravel, routes

Based on [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099903/how-to-apply-regex-to-check-route-param-is-in-array), I want to replicate it but my problem is that the array option has more than 3000 posibilities.
If I do this:

```
Route::get('/example/{example}', 'ExampleController')
->where('example','(example-1|example-2|...|example-3999|example-4000)');
```

I get this error:

```
preg_match(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 72980
```

Is there a way to use `in_array()` or similar in the **where condition** of `route`? With a custom where condition...

A lot of thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My temporal solution is using a custom middleware and apply only to the routes that use this validation.
I don't know if there are a better solution.

```
class CustomMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!in_array($request->example, $arrayList)) abort(404);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/example/{example}', 'ExampleController')->middleware('custom');
```

Comment: There is a catch to this solution if your actual regex matches slashes. E.g. if you had `Route::get('/example/{example}', 'ExampleController')
->where('example','(example/1|example/2|...|example/3999|example/4000)');` this wouldn't work because Laravel would split `example` and the number so you should be aware of this limitation.